# Better highlighting for current selection in diff viewer

Tags: visual-studio-code, diff, git-diff, git-difftool

I'm used to check all my changes before committing anything. Therefore I mainly use the keyboard this way:

- Open the files diff-viewer
- Use shortcut for command `workbench.action.compareEditor.nextChange` to navigate through all changes (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> in my case)

Unfortunately the currently "selected" change is very hard to distinguish from all others, which makes this workflow a little cumbersome:

[image]

I just realized that I could customize this by changing `editor.lineHighlightBackground` or `editor.lineHighlightBorder` but this would change the highlighting of the currently active line in all views which is not what I want.

Can I somehow customize `editor.lineHighlightBorder` only for the diff view?

Something like:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorCursor.foreground": "#f9ae58",

    "[diff]": {
        "editor.lineHighlightBorder": "#fff",
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

In your colorCustomizations just type "`diff`" (without the quotes) and you will see various options like:

```
"diffEditor.removedTextBorder": "#ff0000",
"diffEditor.removedTextBackground": "#ff0000",
"diffEditor.insertedTextBackground": "#ff0000",
"diffEditor.insertedTextBorder": "#ff0000",
```

So no I don't think you can change the currently selected line **only** in the diffEditor.  There is no such option.  Also, the colorCustomizations do not support the language-specific settings like the other settings do.  But maybe playing with the four options above will help?