# How to change background for source control in Vs code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using one dark pro theme as my default VS Code color theme. In that, I am getting source control background as some what light green and dark red for existing and past changes. I would like to change the default color used in the `settings.json`. How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50522339/836330

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can achieve the background change for source control by modifying the `diffEditor` property in workbench configurations of `settings.json`

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "diffEditor.insertedTextBackground": "#045e13c7",
    "diffEditor.removedTextBackground": "#750a2ac0"
  }
```